# Visual Studio 2015 - devenv.exe - Unknown Hard Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When i open a project it fails with

[image]

Anybody has a solution for this?

**I tried those steps:**

1. Restart Computer
2. Restart Visual Studio
3. Start Visual Studio in Safe Mode and reset all windows
4. Deleting my complete project folder and reopen the solution from source control doesnt help
5. Creating a new project works

**Observation:**

- Visual Studio starts normally without loading a project.

Comment: You can create new projects normally? What version was the project originally created in? There's very little to go on here, but hard errors are not specific to VS2015; a quick Google turns up bug reports for VS 2013 that apparantly never have been resolved by MS. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1691800/devenv-exe-crashes-with-unknown-hard-error-when-you-try-to-type-code-which-accesses-a-private-field-in-a-superclass (also this very post, so you're already in the top of Google results, congrats. :)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with my TypeScript Version. On my colleages PC it works. He has a newer TypeScript Version. We will see in a minute ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I wanted to use TypeScript in this project. This dialog came up. I answered with yes.

[image]

But Visual Studio somehow was not able to Update TypeScript.

Next we looked a *Tools > Extensions and Updates* and updated TypeScript manually.

[image]

After the successful TypeScript update the solution opened normally!